# cellForItemAt indexPath gives an issue when collection view is scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have collectionView with one section and numberOfItems in section is 100. I am loading collection view based on the condition in the cellforItemAt indexPath method i.e

```
if (indexPath.row % 5 == 0) {
 cellWidth = 100
} else {
 cellWidth = 50
}
```

This loads the collection view properly but when I scroll collection view is not working as I expected.

Image 1 is what Iam expecting
Image 2 is what I get when collection view is scrolled.

[image: this is what I need]

[image: when I scroll the collection view it changes the UI]

Comment: what is working and what is not expected ?

Comment: Image 1 is what is I expected but when I scroll Up and down the collection View is changing to Image 2.

Comment: What does the condition do actually?

Comment: Try to enable paging in collectionView **collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true**. It works if and only if the red colored label is centered in the UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: @iPeter it decides the width of the content inside the cell.

Comment: What is the exact issue if you please elaborate.

Comment: @Sateesh collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true didn't helped me

Comment: @iPeter I am trying to develop sample project for Ruler which can be used for height selection in cms and weight selection in kilos. In middle I kept rightArrow icon which decides the value user selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decide width of the content inside the cell I recommend using `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` like below:

Firstly conform you controller to protocol `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and implement the method:

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.row % 5 == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: YourCellHeight)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width:50, height: YourCellHeight) 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark the answer accepted if the solution resolved your issue so that it can help other people in future. :)

Answer (score 4):

Because of cells are reusable, instead of giving width values like this I recommend you to change width inside

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if indexPath.row % 5 == 0 {
      return CGSize(width: 100, height:10)
    }else {
      return CGSize(width:50, height:10 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alpher, your solution fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with scrolling that appear also in tableView, there is a function in the CellView called prepareForReuse() that you can use to fix this problem; in your case in this function you should reset the value of cellWidth, because sometimes when scrolling the collectionView, variables get messy

In your CollectionViewCell you can call this function like this

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    cellWidth = nil
}
```

It can be helpful to know if your cell is a custom cell or a normal UICollectionViewCell

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this didn't fix my problem and I am using a normal UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: Okay, so you can use the function sizeForItemAt that other guys posted to you :)